# copying and pasting a user defined range

Tags: excel, vba, copy-paste

I have a spreadsheet where I high light a particular range of values, run a macro and have the selected cell pasted as values in a user defined range.

The following code, which works, takes a user selected range and pastes it into another part of the same workbook.

```
Sub copypaste2()

Selection.Copy

Range("e22").Select

Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    
End Sub
```

I would like to use an input box to select a cell where the selection will be copied; the cell "e22" may not be available, and I have the need to perform this function several times in the spreadsheet.

Thank you in advance for the help!!

Comment: Thank you very much for the new code!!  Works exactly as needed!!!

Answer (score 0):

- Users click `Cancel` button on `InputBox` returns False, `On Error Resume Next` ignores the error.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub copypaste2()
    Dim rCell As Range, rSel As Range
    Set rSel = Selection
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rCell = Application.InputBox("Please select a cell", Type:=8)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If rCell Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    rSel.Copy
    rCell.Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
End Sub
```

**Type** argument:

| Value | Description |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | A formula |
| 1 | A number |
| 2 | Text (a string) |
| 4 | A logical value (True or False) |
| 8 | A cell reference, as a Range object |
| 16 | An error value, such as #N/A |
| 64 | An array of values |

*Microsoft documentation:*

> [Application.InputBox method (Excel)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.inputbox?WT.mc_id=M365-MVP-33461)